# に恥じる (Clarification on に)

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 遠坂がマスターとして行動しているのなら、俺もあいつに恥じない成果を出さないと。
>   If Tohsaka is acting as a master, i have to get results which will not make her feel ashamed.
>
> 人に恥じることはなにもない。
>   People do not feel ashamed for anything.

恥じる: To feel ashamed.
僕が恥じる: I feel ashamed.
僕に恥じる: To feel ashamed towards me.

Is it correct?

I always have troubles understanding when に means "In" and when it means "Towards";"Regarding";"Against".

By In I mean:
There is something to feel ashamed in laughing at people.

And towards:
I feel ashamed about that towards her.
(In my mind this feels something like に対して, but I do not know if it's correct or not. If not please tell me)

Is it there a way to understand this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's one use of 「恥じる」 you may have not been acquainted with.

From 広辞苑 under 「恥じる」:

> ③(多く、否定を伴う)**ひけをとる。劣る。**　【(often accompanied by a negative) **compare unfavorably with; to be inferior**】

As hinted at in the dictionary, in this use the word often appears in the construction 「(~に)恥じない」, which means: "be not inferior to; i.e. **be comparable with**, **be as good as**, or **measure up to** someone/something". Thus:

> 「あいつに恥じない成果」 = "results that are as good as hers/his"

but

> 「人に恥じることはなにもない。」= "There's nothing to be ashamed of (towards people)."

Notice in the latter it's 「に恥じる」, not 「に恥じない」, so that should be a good indicator that it's not used in the sense I mentioned above.

---

As for your questions:

> 恥じる: To feel ashamed.
>   僕が恥じる:I feel ashamed.
>   僕に恥じる:To feel ashamed towards me.
>
> Is it correct?

Correct.

> Is it there a way to understand this?

I have nothing definitive or even terribly pertinent to say about this, but to take your examples:

> There is something to feel ashamed in laughing at people. → 人を笑うということ**には**、どこか恥じるべきところがある。(私なりの訳)

In this particular sentence I feel more comfortable with 「には」 instead of just 「に」, but  using 「に」 would be perfectly grammatical and understandable. Personal preference, maybe.

> I feel ashamed about that towards her. → そのことについて、私は彼女**に**恥じています。(私なりの訳)

In the "towards" or "against" sense, more often than not 「に」 can be replaced with 「に対して」without changing the meaning. Here, 「私は彼女**に対して**恥じています」 would be as acceptable and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

"...に（を）恥じる" is opposite to "...を誇る - to be proud of." So it is all right to translate it as "to feel ashamed of sth." You can also rephrase it with "feel sorry (for)" and "feel embarrassed about, with sth).